# Swift glGetProgramInfoLog

Tags: ios, swift, opengl-es

Does anyone know how to implement this in swift? The entire function call is

```
glGetProgramInfoLog(
  <#program: GLuint#>, 
  <#bufsize: GLsizei#>, 
  <#length: UnsafeMutablePointer<GLsizei>#>, 
  <#infolog: UnsafeMutablePointer<GLchar>#>)
```

I understand passing the pointers but not the buffer sizes. Android doesn't even have these parameters at all.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone looking for an answer you can use following code :

Where program is `let program = glCreateProgram()`

**Swift 2**

```
var message = [CChar](count: 256, repeatedValue: CChar(0))
var length = GLsizei(0)
glGetProgramInfoLog(program, 256, &length, &message)
print(String(UTF8String: message))
```

**Swift 3**

```
var message = [CChar](repeating: CChar(0), count: 256)
var length = GLsizei(0)
glGetProgramInfoLog(program, 256, &length, &message)
var s = String.init(utf8String: message)!
if(s.characters.count > 0){print("Shader compile log: \(s)")} //only prints if log isnt empty
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var message = [CChar](count: 256, repeatedValue: CChar(0))
var length = GLsizei(0)
var log = Array<GLchar>(count: Int(length ), repeatedValue: 0)
log.withUnsafeBufferPointer { logPointer -> Void in
    glGetShaderInfoLog(yourProgram, length, &length, UnsafeMutablePointer(logPointer.baseAddress))
    NSLog("Shader compile log: \n%@", String(UTF8String: log)!)
}
```